# How to change next button to submit/go button on Android mobile softkeyboard in text input field in a HTML form?

Tags: android, html

When I focus Input #1 in this HTML form

```
<form>
  <input placeholder="Input #1" tabindex="-1"></input>
  <input placeholder="Input #2" tabindex="-1"></input>
</form>
```

I see "next" button on my android keyboard, but I have keydown listener which listens for Enter key on this input. How do I change Next button to Go/Submit button without removing or changing listener key?